# Jquery Promises Chaining + Typescript = Type Mismatch

Tags: jquery, typescript, promise

I'm having some difficulties on TS while trying to chain jQuery Promises with .then

See my code below:

```
function first(): JQueryPromise<string>
{
    return $.when('1');
}

function test()
{
    $.when()
        .then(() =>
        {
            return first();
        })
        .then((value) =>
        {
            var str: string = value; //<--- type mismatch here.
        });
}
```

Typescript is expecting that value is of type JQueryPromise instead of "string".

If I cast value to any, I am able to make it work.

Is there a different way to implement it, or is there an error with JQuery definition file?

Thanks

Comment: Your usage looks ok. Type inference for promises is bad/hard try typing it explicitly.

Comment: I used to have the same problem. Strangely enough, upon inspection of the definition file there's no definition of then matching the signature of then that VS' IntelliSense shows or which the compiler complains about. I don't know if TypeScript intellisense is powered by the compiler but if so, I suspect its a compiler bug.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Do you mean to do the following: .then((value: string) =>
 {
  var str: string = value;
 });

Comment: @OliverWeichhold it's a type bug. JavaScript promises are both map and flatMap, a `then` can either be `Promise<T> -> T -> Promise<U> -> Promise<U>` or `Promise<T> -> T -> U -> Promise<U>`, so when you return a promise from a `then` the compiler can't tell which overload you're using since you might be using a promise of a promise. For example if your `.then` return a Promise<string>` it doesn't know if its return is `Promise<string>` or `Promise<Promise<string>>` (is `U` a `Promise<string>` or is `Promise<U>` a `Promise<string>` and `U` is a `string` ?)

Comment: @OliverWeichhold on a scale of 1 to 10, how bad was my last comment? Reading it back it doesn't sound like it was very well phrased given the circumstance.

Comment: I actually i didn't find it so bad at all :-)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum So basically the way that I am implementing is correct, right? Btw, your comment is clear enough. If this is the case, please answer the question and I'll mark it as correct. Thanks

Comment: @HobojoeBr it works when you add explicit type annotations though right?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Do you mean this: `.then((value: string) =>
 {
  var str: string = value;
 });`  If so, it doesn't work. Still a type mismatch, but now on the **.then**

Comment: Yep, it is a problem with the type definition. Interested to see what the best answer is, last time I think I got around it with some liberal casting to `<any>`.

Comment: Verified problem with the definition. You can report it here : https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/issues/ 

BTW the angular `$http` does the right thing. There are other reasons to use $q or `$.ajax` as well

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, trying to penetrate your statement, "JavaScript promises are both map and flatMap". Do you know of a reference that puts more meat on the bones please?

Comment: @Roamer-1888 I'm sorry but if you're going to ask hard questions [you'll get hard and raw reading material](http://esdiscuss.org/topic/promise-cast-and-promise-resolve) from the ESDiscuss list directly - enjoy :)

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum, yes I know that ESDiscuss gets pretty deep. I was hoping for something nice and digestible but thanks anyway. Maybe one day there will be an ESWiki in which the distilled wisdom can reside :-)

Comment: The behaviour of jQuery's "promises" changes between 1.7 and 1.8 and later.  Prior to 1.8 the return of a `then` will not be propagated to chained functions. What version of the jQuery definition file are you using ?

Comment: @RobertSlaney I'm using jQuery 1.9.1.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery promises have a complicated structure in the DefinitelyTyped definition file, for the reason that JQuery promises themselves have a complicated structure/history. You should be able to help the compiler choose the correct overload by providing the generic argument, rather than relying on inference:

```
.then<string>(() =>
{
    return first();
})
```

Also, if you have a lot of work you need to do with promises, I do humbly like to suggest using a library like [Q.js](https://github.com/kriskowal/q). Q is closer to the Promises/A+ specification that is the basis for ES6 promises, it's a simpler defined library so type inferencing tends to work better in TypeScript, and it provides a bunch of useful helper tools like `Q.all`.